# Invoke Lambda function from AWS DataPipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-data-pipeline

Is there a way to invoke a Lambda function from AWS DataPipeline? Looking at the activities available, there isn't a direct way to invoke a lambda from DataPipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, you would use a [shellCommandActivity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-shellcommandactivity.html) to do this but this isn't the right service for what I think the use case is. You may be more interested in step functions.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-creating-lambda-state-machine.html